# How to mock request.Request in golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, request, mocking

I'm using `github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/request` to get presigned URLs, which I need to upload files to s3 bucket in AWS. I'm writing the test currently, for that I need to mock `func (r *Request) Presign(expire time.Duration)`. `request.Request` is a struct, not an interface, so i have no idea, how can I mock it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't directly answering your question, but it might remove the basis of the question altogether.

A neat thing in Go, is that you are able to easily isolate your dependencies using interfaces. If your code, the part that you need to test, is using `Presign` indirectly, it is trivial to test.

I.e. create an interface

```
type HigherLevelAws interface {
    Upload(file string) error
}
```

and use this interface in your code, along with `Upload`. Then you can easily mock this using e.g. https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/mock

The actual implementation, would look something like this

```
type ActualAwsImpl struct {
    aws *aws.Client
}

func (a *ActualAwsImpl) Upload(file string) error {
    aws.Presign...
}
```

This allows you to test the business part of your code, but of course, still leaves untested code in `ActualAwsImpl`. This untested code, however, may be guaranteed to work by virtue of unit and integration tests in the aws sdk itself. 
Either way, in my organization, we test this using fake aws services run in docker (e.g. https://github.com/gliffy/fake-s3).

Comment: Thanks! That helped me enough ;)

Comment: @cupakob Are you able to share how you mocked Presign from request.Request? I'm having that same challenge. I mocked PutObjectRequest (which I call in my code) easily, but that then returns *request.Request and I'm not sure how to mock Presign from that.

Answer (score 1):

I had to Mock a Request for a S3 command. Code below:

```
req, result := r.s3.ListObjectsV2Request(&s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
        Bucket: aws.String(configs.Settings.S3Bucket),
    })

    err := req.Send()
```

The Mock function had to return a Request Object

```
func (m *mockS3ProviderClient) ListObjectsV2Request(input *s3.ListObjectsV2Input) (req *request.Request, output *s3.ListObjectsV2Output) {

    err := input.Validate()
    req = &request.Request{
        HTTPRequest: &http.Request{},
        Error:       err,
    }

    output = &s3.ListObjectsV2Output{
        Contents: []*s3.Object{
            {Key:aws.String("File1")},
            {Key:aws.String("File2")},
        },
    }

    return req, output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface for the function directly, like this:

```
type presigner interface {
    Presign(expire time.Duration) (string, error)
}
```

If you implement your logic in a separate function that takes a `presigner` as a parameter like this (called *dependency injection*):

```
func Upload(p presigner, files string) error {
    // ...
    res, err := p.Presign(someduration)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // and so on
}
```

Then it's easy to mock in your tests - just implement the `presigner` interface and have the `Presign` function return what you expect:

```
type presignerMock struct {}

func (p *presignerMock) Presign(d time.Duration) (string, error) {
    return "yay", nil
}
```

To test different scenarios you can add fields to the `presignerMock` and return them in your implementation:

```
type presignerMock {
    res string
    err error
}

func (p *presignerMock) Presign(d time.Duration) (string, error) {
    return p.res, p.err
}
```